# Xpath select element based on 2 child element conditions

Tags: html, xpath

Here is the html code:

```
<table>
<tr class="WhiteRow">
    <td align="center">
        <input id="SelectedDelivery1" type="checkbox" onclick="HandleClick(this.name,this.checked,"")" value="Y" name="SelectedDelivery1">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <span></span>
        <span class="bold">Instrument Search</span>
        <br>
        abc (TRANSFER)
    </td>
    <td align="center">5 minutes</td>
    <td class="noborder" align="right">
    <td class="noborder" align="right">
    <td class="noborder" align="right">
    <td class="noborder" align="right">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input id="SelectedDelivery2" type="checkbox" onclick="HandleClick(this.name,this.checked,"")" value="Y" name="SelectedDelivery1">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <span></span>
        <span class="bold">Instrument Search</span>
        <br>
        abc (CAVEAT)
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to target the `<tr>` containing `<span class="bold">Instrument Search</span>` and `abc (TRANSFER)`. That tr may not be the first element in the table.

So far I tried

```
//td/span[text()="Instrument Search"]/ancestor::tr
```

which only satisfy one of the condition, and there are a few tr that satisfy the selector.

Could you please advise me how to target both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XPath expression:

```
//tr[contains(., 'abc (TRANSFER)') and contains(td/span[@class = 'bold'], 'Instrument Search')]
```

If possible, you should always use expressions that are unidirectional, because a "backwards" axis like `ancestor::` could be a costly move. That's the advantage over the solution you have found already.

If the `span[@class = 'bold']` cannot contain anything else than "Instrument Search", you should modifiy the expression above to:

```
//tr[contains(., 'abc (TRANSFER)') and td/span[@class = 'bold'] = 'Instrument Search']
```

The location of "abc (TRANSFER)" is still not very precise, if it is required in a certain place (e.g. always inside a `td` element) you'd have to further restrict the above.

---

**EDIT** Respondin to your comment:

> abc (TRANSFER) is inside td tag, it's just a text field

Then use

```
//tr[contains(td, 'abc (TRANSFER)') and td/span[@class = 'bold'] = 'Instrument Search']
```

Comment: `abc (TRANSFER)` is inside `td` tag, it's just a text field

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer after crawling through the syntax.
Please let me know if there is any other better ways

```
//td/span[text()="Instrument Search"]/ancestor::td/text()[contains(., "TRANSFER")]/ancestor::tr
```